# how to load xml into plist

Tags: xml, uitableview, plist

Just looking for some good examples or example code on how to load xml into a plist file?

I have done similar things with uitableview but not sure what I have to think about doing with plist.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear on what exactly you mean by loading xml into a plist file.  If you are trying to write out your app's data into a XML plist file, then you could put that data into a dictionary and then just call:

```
  -writeToFile:atomically:
```

Loading it back from that file into the app is similarly easy:

```
  -dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:
```

On the other hand, if you are getting XML from, say, the network, and want to save it into a plist file, then it could be as easy as putting the XML in an NSData object and the writing that with:

```
-writeToFile:
```

But that depends on the exact format of the XML you have and whether you want a readable plist or a binary one.

Alternatively, you will have to parse your XML into a dictionary and then write that dictionary out as above.

I'll need more details of what you are trying to do to be able to give you more guidance.